# How can I flag content programmatically?

Tags: 8, flags

The [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module is still in development for Drupal 8, but it's working nice. However, I didn't find how to add a flag programmatically; the [API documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1748148) seems to speak of the Drupal 7 version.

How do I programmatically add a flag?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how to flag or unflag an entity programmatically, using the Flag service.

```
$flag_id = 'bookmark';

$flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
$flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);

// Flag an entity with a specific flag.
$flag_service->flag($flag, $entity);

// Unflag an entity with a specific flag.
$flag_service->unflag($flag, $entity);

$flag->save();
```

Comment: In some case, i need to check if a content is not already flagged because double flagging produce an error. I will post an answer with an example.

Comment: where to put above code

Comment: Thanks, this save me a lot of time ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Flag for a certain user you will have to do :

```
$account = \Drupal::currentUser(); // or load a specific user
$flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');

$flag = $flag_service->getFlagById('bookmark'); // replace by flag machine name

// check if already flagged
$flagging = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $media, $account);
if (!$flagging) {
  $flag_service->flag($flag, $media, $account);
}
else {
  $flag_service->unflag($flag, $media, $account);
}
```

Comment: What is $media?

Comment: In my case it is a drupal Media object, but it could be any type of drupal Entity. Like a node for example.