# How can I write into a Flag's custom field programmatically?

Tags: 8, flags

I successfully managed to save a flag programmatically in Drupal 8 thanks to [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222941/how-can-i-flag-content-programmatically) help but I cannot manage to save data into a custom field I added to the flag entity.

The following code saves the flag but the field stay empty.

```
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($entity_id);
$flag_id = 'bookmark';
$flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
$flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);

/* Here is where I'm trying to set my custom field value */
$flag->set('field_my_custom_field', $link_name);

$flag_service->flag($flag, $entity);
```

I cannot find any info into the documentation. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  Have you tried `$flag->save();` after the set?

Comment: Hi @leymannx, thanks :). Yes, that was my first try but no luck with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fix it with this code.
You should save the output of the function

```
$flag_service->flag($flag, $entity);   //Wrong method
```

in a variable like it

```
$id_flagged_entity = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $entity);
```

and set the title at this entity

```
$id_flagged_entity->set("field_my_custom_field", $link_name);
$id_flagged_entity->save();
```

Comment: That's it! It works like a charm, thank you!